# How to swap textures in batch for multiple objects?

Tags: python, texturing, scripting

I need to change the texture file type of my textures from **.dds** to **.png** so that I can export them in an fbx.

Since I'm handling thousands of objects with hundreds of textures I need some sort of automated approach since manually swapping out the textures for over 12 thousand objects would take years.

I have found a [thread that goes into this issue](https://blenderartists.org/t/whats-the-fastest-way-to-change-textures-for-100-objects/665100/7).

I tried using the suggested python script like this:

```
import bpy
for img in bpy.data.images:
    img.filepath = img.filepath.replace('.dds', '.png')
    img.reload()
```

I placed the converted textured with the png ending in the same directory as the old dds textures. They have the same name and only differ in their file endings. I'm not very familiar with python nor scripting in blender so I'm a little lost since running this script doesn't do anything.

Does anybody know what I could try to solve this?

Comment: if your png files are indeed in the same directory as your dds files, this script should work. i just tested it and it works.

Comment: That's odd - Do I need to select something for it to work properly?
So far I've simply opened the Scripting tab, created a new text, pasted in the code and then pressed the "run script" button. The run script even shows up in the info tab, but when I hover over the textures on objects it still says .dds

[https://gyazo.com/011dc40a7d4b7f14ee754cf6a8e45fe9]
[https://gyazo.com/78e0043522460c1ba7394a1ba6204e32]

Comment: just running the script should have worked. so it's odd that it didn't in your case. try a new simple setup with new blend file and have 2 image files with same name but .png and .jpg but make sure the picture content is something else so u can see it toggle to the other pic when running script. then a cube with 1 face having the Image Texture.

Comment: I'll give it a shot real quick.

Comment: Okay so this is interesting. It did visibly swap out the texture, however in the material tab it still says that it's using the .dds file even though the png file is being displayed on the object

Comment: thats ok. its just the original name string used as dictionary key in the bpy.data.images[key]. its a relic of the past, but the image data is the new one :D

Comment: Ohhh okay that's a relief. I'll try importing the fbx to see if it works as intended now :)

Comment: i actually just found out today XD

Comment: Haha, that makes two of us then! I tried reimporting and everything seems to be working properly. I'll have to see how to make the transparency work inside Unreal Engine, but that's another thing altogether. THanks so much for your help!